# Is there a way to make the kernel treat a block device like it has a larger than 4k block size?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block, kernel-module

Harkening back to this question, which is now 4 years old...

[Bypassing 4KB block size limitation on block layer/device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30585565/bypassing-4kb-block-size-limitation-on-block-layer-device)

I'm a kernel newbie, so I don't know too much which is why I'm asking here.
I know the 512 byte sector is the center of the linux universe. And I know from trying it out that if I create a block device passing blk_queue_logical_block_size() anything larger than 4096, I get BUG null pointer exceptions in the kernel, probably for the reason Theo Ts'o explains in the above question.

He mentions having to do the read-update-write sequence which the kernel does already. Maybe this is something that has changed.
If I create a block device with 4k blocks and I dd 1 byte into the first block, the kernel does a read, updates the one byte and issues me a write for that one block.

Actually it issues 4 4k reads I assume that's a proactive prefetch.
What I was wondering is if there's a setting in the kernel that would still allow for 4k blocks internally in the kernel so it wouldn't cause problems with the 4k page size, but have the kernel present larger-than-4k blocks to my block device.

All of the read-update-write stuff is in there somewhere, and as that above question is 4 years old, I thought maybe some changes have occurred that might make the answer different nowadays..

There's a bunch of other functions (blk_queue_physical_block_size, blk_queue_max_segment_size, etc) that I'm not 100% sure how they work.

All the block device articles I've googled for don't take this question into account.

Does anybody know if it is possible in the linux kernel (current versions are fine) to get it to treat a block device as if it has larger than 4k blocks?

Thanks for any pointers or tips along the way, again I'm a bit newbie at this.

This is a virtual block device driver I'm writing, it doesn't map to a physical disk, so the block size doesn't have to match any kind of existing hardware requirements.

Comment: If I were you I'd post the question on lkml.

Comment: Treated like dirt?  No, never seen that -- only the old heads chew eachother out now & then.  You might also try mailing Theo Ts'o directly. Be sure to be succinct and pick a good Subject line.

Comment: it takes a brave man to write theo directly.... okay, I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: Be sure also to peruse this here: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/

Comment: Note that you need to subscribe to lkml first. I can't see readily how to do that anymore -- it's been some time -- it might be in this FAQ: http://vger.kernel.org/lkml/.

Comment: I subscribed, they make it... less than obvious

Comment: Good luck in your excursions into the greatest success story of open source software ever, that will celebrate its 30th birthday one of these days. Do not be daunted!

Comment: It's not at all clear what you are trying to do.   *Why* do you want a block device with a logical block size > 16kb?   What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Imagine something sorta like the hadoop file system thing. Where little 4k blocks don't help when the mean size of a given pile of data is much larger than 4k. So my block device will be backed by some nebulous thing I haven't all worked out yet, but the application writing the data to the block device is never going to write less than 32k or 64k or maybe someday never write less than 1 meg. Is that possible to manage in the kernel? If not, I can just do the read-update-write myself, but if it's already possible in the kernel I'd rather do it that way.

Comment: oh right, so maybe I didn't explain out the exact point. larger blocks go faster right? the fewer calls for a given pile of data the faster everything goes, otherwise we'd all be using 1 byte blocks. :-)

Comment: and I guess the other point is that if the kernel can already handle this situation, then there's no point in me writing code to handle the same thing, since it's already done, and I just need to find out what settings to poke to make it work.